# What is the Purpose of assigning width 100% to the div of class 'form'?

Tags: html, css, forms

Is it neccessary to always add width 100% to all div's within a parent container?
What are the standards coz i have noticed some people leaving it out while others use it.

Like in the code below, what is the purpose of adding width = 100% in the div with the class of form inside the div with the class wrapper ?

Can Someone explain this? within the context of this code.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;700&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

body {
  background: #fec107;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 30px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125)
}

.wrapper .title {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  color: #fec107;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}


/* This class here.... */

.wrapper .form {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="title">
      Registration Form
    </div>
    <div class="form">
      <div class="input-field">
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="input">
      </div>
      <div class="input-field">
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="input">
      </div>
      <div class="input-field">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="input">
      </div>
      <div class="input-field">
        <label>Confirm Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="input">
      </div>
      <div class="input-field">
        <label>Gender</label>
        <div class="custom-select">
          <select>
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="male">Male</option>
            <option value="female">Female</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field">
        <label>Email Address</label>
        <input type="email" class="input">
      </div>
      <div class="input-field">
        <label>Phone Number</label>
        <input type="number" class="input">
      </div>
      <div class="input-field">
        <label>Address</label>
        <textarea class="textarea"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field">
        <label>Postal Code</label>
        <input type="number" class="input">
      </div>
      <div class="input-field terms">
        <label class="check">
                <input type="checkbox">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
        <p>Agreed to terms and conditions</p>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field">
        <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Really confused on this...

Comment: In the given code, setting `width: 100%;` on `.wrapper .form` ensures that the form takes up the full width of its container. It's useful for making the form responsive and maintaining consistency in styling, but it might be redundant if block-level elements already naturally expand to the full width by default.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, `div` have a display of block by default, which automatically has a width of 100%.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize my opinion, the `width:100%` on the `form` within the `wrapper` makes the `form` fill the entire width of its containing element(the `wrapper`).
So we can see responsive and visually appealing layout.

The main part which makes form responsive:

```
.wrapper {
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 30px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
}

.wrapper .form {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Hope to be helpful for understanding.